# Recommendations for a small to mid sized camera bag which will hold a laptop?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag, laptop

I'm doing research on a camera bag. I'm looking for a small book bag to carry my d70 with 18-70 attached, a 70-300, my 8-16, and MacBook pro. I'm interested in finding a camera bag that can also hold a computer. So, the primary focus on the bag should be camera. I've looked at a lot of bags and the smaller ones that hold computers don't seem to utilize the camera space well enough.

I narrowed my choice down to the [Manfrotto Veloce V Backpack](http://www.manfrotto.com/veloce-v-backpack-white). Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Get two bags; one for your laptop, one for your camera. Because the devices are such entirely different shapes, using the same bag for both will either compromise the integrity of one item or the other, or both.

Comment: Please read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/. I think this question could be rephrased in a way that makes it more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is really going to help you, but I also use separate bags; when doing photography I take a camera bag (a ThinkTank Retrospective 10 most of the time, or a LowePro SlingShot).   When going to work I carry my laptop in the backpack designed for it, and put my DSLR (with one lens and battery grip) also in the bag.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Tenba Messenger Camera Large bag. I love it. But it will *not* hold my Mac Book Pro 15". It probably will hold a 13" or Air.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great luck with Lowepro, both the Fastback when I need the laptop and more gear (Canon T1i with Tamron 18-270, Canon 50, Canon 10-20) and the MacBook Pro 15" in the sleeve, but room for more gear.

I dont like carrying a lot, so w/o the laptop, I switch to one of the [Lowepro sling packs](http://products.lowepro.com/product/SlingShot-100-AW,2034,4.htm). I can usually get the camera body in the top if I am taking the big 300mm lens. This one is nice because it has the rain cover (my Fastpack does not seem to have one)

Answer (score 0):

I use the Case Logic SLR Camera and Laptop Backpack (SLRC-206) ([youtube video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXeDVtELLZo))
and I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Fastpack [250](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Fastpack-250,2086,14.htm) or [350](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Fastpack-350,2087,14.htm) by Lowepro

Answer (score 0):

Tenba Messenger - I have the medium size, it's the best bag I've ever had. It's got everything and is very comfortable to carry. You may need bigger if your laptop is large.